# PHP imagick not working for a certain photo

Tags: php, imagick

There is a large .jpeg photo that one of the users on my site is unable to upload.

I tried to share the photo here, but it took 5+ minutes to get uploaded and still didn't upload so I had to cancel the upload.

Here is a link to the photo online

http://www.comehike.com/img/member_photo/30/DSCN0175.JPG

But when imagick tried to process it, the page was just hanging and eventually reached the end of max request time and just became a white page.  I even increased the request time to 500 seconds, and it still didn't work.

Comment: It's 5MB 3648px x 2736px

Comment: @pavium I have a 10MB limit.  Can it be a problem?  This is very mysterious :)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is just too big. You can limit the max size of the upload by getting the size with `$_FILES['field_name']['size']`and reject the upload.

Comment: What makes you say that the file is too big?  For me it shows that it is about 5MB and my max allowed size is 10MB.

Comment: Because I think that due of the big size of the image, the processor of the server is to slow to process the operation. So after a timeout, a white page is displayed. You can maybe find more information about imageMagick here : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: I think that you can try to increase the max limit time of an operation. You can find more informations about this here : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php - There is an environment variable MAGICK_TIME_LIMIT and policies that you can modify in policy.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think PHP's `upload_max_filesize` default is just 2M. Try to increase `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini.  It's probably also necessary to increase `post_max_size` to the same or larger value accordingly.

Comment: my upload_max_filesize is 10MB and post_max_size is 8MB, and as far as I can tell the file is about 5MB.  Or am I missing something?